# Remove white space from concatenated string fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, trim, concatenation

I have 3 fields I am concatenating and it's working just fine in my query, but I cannot resolve how to remove the whitespace from the merged data in the concat field.

```
TRIM(CONCAT(c.data1,c.data2)) AS concat_done
```

**Result:**

```
concat_done
33 0250S 0450E 028NW
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

instead of

```
TRIM(CONCAT(c.data1,c.data2)) AS concat_done
```

try

```
REPLACE(CONCAT(c.data1,c.data2), ' ', '') AS concat_done
```

Comment: Well I'm feeling a bit competent. I was just experimenting with REPLACE() and you nailed it. Worked perfect. Thx. Will accept your answer after 8 minutes (sys won't let me now).

Answer (score 5):

add a [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) call:

```
REPLACE(TRIM(etc...), ' ', '')
                       ^--one space
                            ^-- no spaces
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should probably show your input as well as your output.

Second, [trim() removes leading and trailing spaces](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim), so it looks like you want `concat(trim(var1), trim(var2))` rather than trimming the concatenated version, which now has the spaces on the inside.

**update:** Or, as the other answers say, just use replace(). But this is why trim() wasn't working the way you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Table_1 set Column_1= TRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(Column_1,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''));
```

Also you can use more `replace` functions into inner `replace`.